# ¿Cual es la mejor forma de plantear tareas recurrentes en Android?

Tags: android

Quiero que un servicio corra en el móvil permanentemente y cada X tiempo ejecute unas determinadas acciones. Por el momento lo tengo planteado con un alarma que lanza un PendingIntent

```
PendingIntent alarma = PendingIntent.getActivity(Inicio.this, i, tarea, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarioPospuesto.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 1440, alarma);
```

La duda que tengo es si no hay un planteamiento más robusto y eficiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde el punto de vista de diseño de Android, no es deseable que haya código ejecutándose siempre en segundo plano, pues esto evita que la CPU duerma, incrementando notablemente el uso de la batería (pues has de usar un `wake lock` para que el código siga ejecutándose).
Por otra parte, no existe un mecanismo que te garantice que un servicio esté ejecutándose permanentemente (quizás usando el horroroso *sticky*), dado que los servicios están atados a las aplicaciones, el usuario siempre puede *matar* el servicio desde un gestor de tareas.

Es por ello que la aproximación que estás usando actualmente es la mas idónea:

1. No tienes código haciendo `wake lock` de la CPU permanentemente.
2. Mientras el método `onReceive()` se esté ejecutando tienes garantizado el `wake lock`.
3. No habrá servicio que cerrar por parte del usuario, por lo que tendrás mas garantías de que tu código se ejecutará.

Ten en cuenta que has de re suscribir las alarmas si el dispositivo se reinicia, aunque esto es algo que tienes que controlar también con la otra implementación.

Mas información sobre el `wake lock` [aquí](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)

Comment: Si quieres complementar la respuesta puedes hacer refernecia a https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Comment: Gracias, @Webserveis, lo agrego

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración @tomacco